# Path in SwiftUI can not be constructed

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I'm trying to create a view with specific corners rounded.
But I keep getting this Error:

'Path' cannot be constructed because it has no accessible initializers

Here is what I'm doing:

```
struct CornerRadiusShape: Shape {
    var radius = CGFloat.infinity
    var corners = UIRectCorner.allCorners

    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: rect, byRoundingCorners: corners, cornerRadii: CGSize(width: radius, height: radius))
        return Path(path.cgPath)
    }
}

struct CornerRadiusStyle: ViewModifier {
    var radius: CGFloat
    var corners: UIRectCorner

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .clipShape(CornerRadiusShape(radius: radius, corners: corners))
    }
}

extension View {
    func cornerRadius(_ radius: CGFloat, corners: UIRectCorner) -> some View {
        ModifiedContent(content: self, modifier: CornerRadiusStyle(radius: radius, corners: corners))
    }
}
```

If you know any other solutions for doing this, I would love to know.

Comment: Works fine here, Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5. Where did you see that error? Maybe you have some type names conflict.

Comment: in the line that I'm converting cgPath to Path. that's where i get that error

Comment: i'm importing SwiftUI only. maybe i need to import something else too?

Comment: That is very basic and public constructor since iOS 13, look for other Path type in your project code. Ah... clean-delete derived sources-rebuild-restart Xcode... also sometimes helps :)

Comment: Yeah the issue was exactly what you said:)  i had an enum called Path that was handling some url paths. Thanks for the help!